# Flutter Firebase Phone Authentication with BLoC

Tags: firebase, flutter, async-await, firebase-authentication, bloc

I'm trying to achieve Firebase phone authentication with BLoC pattern.

This is my bloc class

```
class AuthBloc extends Bloc<AuthEvent, AuthState> {
  final AuthProvider authProvider;

  AuthBloc({this.authProvider}) : assert(authProvider!= null);

  @override
  AuthState get initialState => Uninitialized();

  @override
  Stream<AuthState> mapEventToState(AuthEvent event) async* {
    if (event is AppLaunched) {
      yield* _mapAppLaunchedToState();
    } else if(event is OtpRequested) {
      yield* _mapOtpRequestedToState();
    } else if (event is LoggedIn) {
      yield* _mapLoggedInToState();
    } else if (event is LoggedOut) {
      yield* _mapLoggedOutToState();
    }
  }

  Stream<AuthState> _mapAppLaunchedToState() async* {
    try {
      final isSignedIn = await authProvider.isLoggedIn();

      if (isSignedIn) {
        final name = userProvider.firebaseUser;
        yield Authenticated(name);
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated();
      }
    } catch (_) {
      yield Unauthenticated();
    }
  }

  Stream<AuthState> _mapOtpRequestedTostate() async* {
    yield AuthInProgress();
    try {
      FirebaseUser firebaseUser = await authProvider.verifyPhone();

      if (firebaseUser != null) {
        yield Authenticated(firebaseUser);
      } else {
        yield Unauthenticated();
      }
    } catch(_, stacktrace) {
      yield Unauthenticated();
    }
  }

  Stream<AuthState> _mapLoggedInToState() async* {
    yield Authenticated(userProvider.firebaseUser);
  }

  Stream<AuthState> _mapLoggedOutToState() async* {
    yield Unauthenticated();
    authProvider.signOutUser();
  }
}
```

This is the AuthProvider

```
class AuthProvider extends BaseAuthProvider {
  String _verificationId;
  FirebaseUser user;
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth;

  AuthProvider(
      {FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth})
      : _firebaseAuth = firebaseAuth ?? FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @override
  Future<FirebaseUser> verifyPhone() async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationCompleted =
        (AuthCredential phoneAuthCredential) async {
          user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(phoneAuthCredential)).user;
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      print(
          'Phone number verification failed. Code: ${authException.code}. Message: ${authException.message}');
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent codeSent =
        (String verificationId, [int forceResendingToken]) async {
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout codeAutoRetrievalTimeout =
        (String verificationId) {
      _verificationId = verificationId;
    };

    await _firebaseAuth.verifyPhoneNumber(
        phoneNumber: _phoneNumberProvider.number,
        timeout: const Duration(seconds: 5),
        verificationCompleted: verificationCompleted,
        verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
        codeSent: codeSent,
        codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: codeAutoRetrievalTimeout);

    return user;
  }

  Future<FirebaseUser> signInWithPhone() async {
    final AuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
      verificationId: _verificationId,
      smsCode: _otpProvider.number,
    );
    final FirebaseUser user =
        (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)).user;
    final FirebaseUser currentUser = await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
    assert(user.uid == currentUser.uid);

    if (user != null) {
      return currentUser;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  @override
  Future<void> signOutUser() async {
    return Future.wait([_firebaseAuth.signOut()]); // terminate the session
  }

  @override
  Future<FirebaseUser> getCurrentUser() async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.currentUser(); //retrieve the current user
  }

  @override
  Future<bool> isLoggedIn() async {
    final user =
        await _firebaseAuth.currentUser(); //check if user is logged in or not
    return user != null;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {}
}
```

When the verifyPhone from AuthBloc is called it gets executed async and which in turn calls the mcallbacks which are again async. So the _mapOtpRequestedToState() will be finished before we get back the FirebaseUser from AuthProvider. Hence Authenticated State is not being yielded and user is not getting logged in.

Help is needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think that most of the time, a code that is readable is much better.

The following sample implements the logic you intended to write, using an (Action -> Event) mechanism:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Provider<AppStateBloc>(
      builder: (_) => AppStateBloc(),
      dispose: (_, bloc) {
        bloc.dispose();
      },
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: TestPage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class TestPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AppStateBloc appStateBloc = Provider.of<AppStateBloc>(context, listen: false);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Flow Test')),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          StreamBuilder<AppState>(
            stream: appStateBloc.stateOut,
            initialData: AppState.initial,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<AppState> snapshot) {
              AppState state = snapshot.data;

              return Column(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Current State: $state'),
                  SizedBox(height: 10.0),
                  if (state == AppState.initial || state == AppState.failure)
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => appStateBloc.actionIn(AppStateAction.login),
                      child: Text('Authenticate'),
                    ),

                  if (state == AppState.authenticated)
                    RaisedButton(
                      onPressed: () => appStateBloc.actionIn(AppStateAction.logout),
                      child: Text('Logout'),
                    ),

                ],
              );
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class AppStateBloc {
  StreamController<AppState> _controllerState = StreamController<AppState>.broadcast();
  Stream<AppState> get stateOut => _controllerState.stream;
  Function(AppState) get _stateIn => _controllerState.sink.add;

  StreamController<AppStateAction> _controllerAction = StreamController<AppStateAction>.broadcast();
  Function(AppStateAction) get actionIn => _controllerAction.sink.add;

  StreamSubscription _subscription;

  AppStateBloc() {
    _subscription = _controllerAction.stream.listen(_businessLogic);
  }

  // All the business logic comes here
  void _businessLogic(AppStateAction action) async {
    switch (action) {

      case AppStateAction.login:
        // do authentication
        User user = await fakeAuthenticator.verifyUser();
        if (user == null) {
          _stateIn(AppState.failure);
        } else {
          _stateIn(AppState.authenticated);
        }
        break;

      case AppStateAction.logout:
        // do what needs to be done in this case
        await fakeAuthenticator.logout();
        _stateIn(AppState.initial);
        break;

      default:
        // nothing
        break;
    }
  }

  void dispose() {
    _subscription?.cancel();
    _controllerAction?.close();
    _controllerState?.close();
  }
}

enum AppStateAction {
  none,
  login,
  logout,
}

enum AppState {
  initial,
  authenticated,
  failure,
}

class User {}

class FakeAuthenticator {
  User _user;

  Future<User> verifyUser() async {
    // Simulation of Authentication made at server side
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    // Successful authentication
    _user = User();

    return _user;
  }

  Future<void> logout() async {
    // Simulation of Authentication made at server side
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1));

    _user = null;
  }

  User get user => _user;

  // ------- Singleton
  static final FakeAuthenticator _instance = FakeAuthenticator._internal();
  factory FakeAuthenticator() => _instance;
  FakeAuthenticator._internal();
}

FakeAuthenticator fakeAuthenticator = FakeAuthenticator();
```

The main difference with your code is that with this one, but this is my personal feeling, you are more "in control" of your business logic.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I was able to login a user. I used the Singleton class to make it work.

Comment: Can u help me how u did it? i m also facing same issue.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I had my semester exams.

Coming to the problem, I made my AuthBloc singleton, so that I was able to pass the same object around. By this I was able to send authbloc object to authprovider and able change the state there.